# What are salesforce.com and Apex like as an application development platform?

Tags: apex

I have seen a post about Salesforce "What are salesforce.com and Apex like as an application development platform?" which is really old but raised some pertinent questions about the inefficiency of Salesforce as application development tool.

It would be great to revisit this question and listen to expert comments on how Salesforce has evolved over time. What are the constraints still remaining?

Can we build an entire standalone application with Apex alone? Has the deployment tools gotten better with time with the introduction of Salesforce DX and the leaning of Salesforce towards open source frameworks?

Would you recommend Salesforce to developers now for building applications? @Ben, @Sfdcfox

Comment: I feel such opiniated questions are more suited on twitter, salesforce developer forum , reddit

Comment: But there is no dearth of it on StackExchange as well, as i keep reading these opinionated questions here.It's informative to gather such sharp technical perspective of experts, which is arguably missing from those forums you mentioned.No?

Comment: For me, it is unclear what you are asking. What you do mean by a "standalone application"? Clearly Apex is never actually "standalone" because it only runs on the Salesforce platform. You can't create a .exe with it. So, please update your question to actually explain that it is you are trying to do.

Comment: FYI, at-mentions in the question body (or an answer body) won't alert the user to the presence of the question or answer. If you're actively trying to bring something to someone's attention, use the at-mention in a comment.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Anyway I think this topic was closed as an off-topic subject and i have to shoot it on some other platform as suggested.